# Evaluate the moments of function $F=\left(\frac{X}{k_1}-\frac{Y}{k_2}\right)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

The two independent random variable $X$ and $Y$ which takes the values $A$ and $B$ with the probabilities of $p$ and $q=1-p$ respectively. Consider a function $F$ given as $$F=\left(\frac{X}{k_1}-\frac{Y}{k_2}\right)$$

Here $k_1$ and $k_2$ are constant. Now I want to Evaluate $\mathbb{E}[F]$ and $\mathbb{E}[F^2]$

> **My Attempt** I am not sure $$\mathbb{E}[F]=\left(\frac{pA}{k_1}-\frac{pA}{k_2}\right)+ \left(\frac{pA}{k_1}-\frac{qB}{k_2}\right)+\left(\frac{qB}{k_1}-\frac{pA}{k_2}\right)+\left(\frac{qB}{k_1}-\frac{qB}{k_2}\right)$$
>    \begin{align}
> \mathbb{E}[F^2]=& E\left[\left(\frac{X}{k_1}-\frac{Y}{k_2}\right)^2\right]\\
> =& E\left[\left(\frac{X}{k_1}\right)^2-\left(\frac{2XY}{k_1k_2}\right)+\left(\frac{Y}{k_2}\right)^2\right] \\
> =& \left(p\left(\frac{A}{k_1}\right)^2-p^2\left(\frac{2A^2}{k_1k_2}\right)+p\left(\frac{A}{k_2}\right)^2\right)+\left(q\left(\frac{B}{k_1}\right)^2-q^2\left(\frac{2B^2}{k_1k_2}\right)+q\left(\frac{B}{k_2}\right)^2\right)+\left(p\left(\frac{A}{k_1}\right)^2-pq\left(\frac{2AB}{k_1k_2}\right)+q\left(\frac{B}{k_2}\right)^2\right)+\left(q\left(\frac{B}{k_1}\right)^2-qp\left(\frac{2BA}{k_1k_2}\right)+p\left(\frac{A}{k_2}\right)^2\right)\end{align} 
>   **Edit-1** According to Nadiels Answer \begin{align}\mathbb{E}[F]=&p^2\left(\frac{A}{k_1}-\frac{A}{k_2}\right)+ pq\left(\frac{A}{k_1}-\frac{B}{k_2}\right)+pq\left(\frac{B}{k_1}-\frac{A}{k_2}\right)+q^2\left(\frac{B}{k_1}-\frac{B}{k_2}\right)\\
> =&p\left(\frac{A}{k_1}-\frac{A}{k_2}\right)+q\left(\frac{B}{k_1}-\frac{B}{k_2}\right)
> \end{align}
>    \begin{align}
> \mathbb{E}[F^2]=& E\left[\left(\frac{X}{k_1}-\frac{Y}{k_2}\right)^2\right]\\
> =& E\left[\left(\frac{X}{k_1}\right)^2-\left(\frac{2XY}{k_1k_2}\right)+\left(\frac{Y}{k_2}\right)^2\right] \\
> =& p^2\left(\left(\frac{A}{k_1}\right)^2-\left(\frac{2A^2}{k_1k_2}\right)+\left(\frac{A}{k_2}\right)^2\right)+q^2\left(\left(\frac{B}{k_1}\right)^2-\left(\frac{2B^2}{k_1k_2}\right)+\left(\frac{B}{k_2}\right)^2\right)+pq\left(\left(\frac{A}{k_1}\right)^2-\left(\frac{2AB}{k_1k_2}\right)+\left(\frac{B}{k_2}\right)^2\right)+qp\left(\left(\frac{B}{k_1}\right)^2-\left(\frac{2BA}{k_1k_2}\right)+\left(\frac{A}{k_2}\right)^2\right)\\
> =& p\left(\left(\frac{A}{k_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{A}{k_2}\right)^2\right)+q\left(\left(\frac{B}{k_1}\right)^2+\left(\frac{B}{k_2}\right)^2\right)-\frac{2}{k_1k_2}\left(p^2A^2+q^2B^2+pqAB+pqAB\right) \end{align}

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Also, do you know more about the relation between $X$ and $Y$? If you don't know that they are independent, or more generally their joint distribution, then you'll be in trouble trying to evaluate $\mathbb{E}[F^2]$.

Comment: They are independent

Comment: Okay, with that information, both questions are doable (with answers in terms of $A$ and $B$). What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have added my attempt. Is it correct??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to calculate these expectations, letting $f(x,y)$ be a function then you have that
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[ f(X,Y) \right] = &f(A,A)\cdot \mathbb{P}\left\{X=A,Y=A\right\} + f(A,B)\cdot\mathbb{P}\left\{ X=A,Y=B\right\} \\
&+ f(B,A)\cdot \mathbb{P}\left\{X=B,Y=A\right\} + f(B,B)\cdot\mathbb{P}\left\{ X=B,Y=B\right\},
\end{align}
$$
now looking at your first attempt you have terms such as
$$
f(A,B)\cdot \mathbb{P}\left\{X=A,Y=B\right\} = \left( p\frac{A}{k_1} - q\frac{B}{k_2}\right)
$$
when what you *really* mean is 
$$
f(A,B)\cdot \mathbb{P}\left\{X=A,Y=B\right\} = \left( \frac{A}{k_1} - \frac{B}{k_2}\right)pq
$$
where the independence has been used. You have made that mistake in the second part also, so correct that and you should get a correct solution, hopefully you see what I mean about the difference between the way you have substituted in the $p$ and $q$ terms and the correct way using the joint probabilities.

Some additional comments - your function is linear! So we have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{k_1} - \frac{Y}{k_2} \right] = \frac{1}{k_1}\mathbb{E}\left[X\right] - \frac{1}{k_2}\mathbb{E}\left[ Y \right].
$$
The second term will be easy enough to work out keeping in mind what I said above about how the expectation is calculated, but also use the fact that as far as I can workout from the wording of your question $X,Y$ have the same distribution, and therefore the same moments so once you have lifted the constants $k_1,k_2$ out you are just calculating the expected value of $X$ and $X^2$.

Comment: Thanks. I have made an edit. Do you think now it is correct.

Comment: Hi that is looking much better, but now there is a lot of cancellation to do, so for example you have $q=1-p$, and therefore $p^2 \frac{A}{k_1} + pq\frac{A}{k_1} = p^2\frac{A}{k_1} + p(1-p)\frac{A}{k_1} = p\frac{A}{k_1}$, and this will happen for all of those other terms involving squares, and the easiest way of getting this result is actually to split the expression up using the linearity into a term involving only $X$ and only $Y$ and then evaluate

Comment: Thanks for your comment but now I am more concerned whether it is correct or not.

Comment: Yeah it looks correct, but as I said there is a lot of cancellation you could do yet and it is often the case that these things aren't viewed as correct until they are in their simplest form.

Comment: Hi, I have made the simplification. Do you think now it is correct??

Comment: That is looking pretty good to me! One tiny thing in the very last line would be writing $pqAB + pqAB$ as $2pqAB$, but yeah looks good to me.

Comment: or forming the quadratic there as $(pA + qB)^2$, but those are pretty tiny changes, and that is getting more towards personal preferences rather than objectively better.